# How can I continue a nested conversation in a separate file

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am not a professional programmer but I'm trying to build a python-telegram-bot for work using ConversationHandlers. Basically, I offer users a menu of options, summarized as:

- Complete Survey
- EXIT

If "Complete Survey" is selected, the bot then asks for the user ID. Depending on the user ID I assign the user 1 of 30+ different surveys (I'm trying to use child conversations). Over time this list of surveys will grow and each survey has unique questions and steps to it.

Given the number of surveys, I thought of managing each survey as a child conversation with its own ConversationHandler, and running it from a separate file/module (to keep things dynamic and not have one HUGE file with n+ variables to consider).

The thing is, how can I continue the child conversation from a separate file? Is there another way to approach this? I understand that the bot is still running from the main file and checking for updates. I would like to run each survey and, once finished, return to the INITIAL bot menu (parent conversation).

I found this previous discussion but my knowledge barely goes beyond the python-telegram-bot examples so I'm having a hard time following along: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/2388

Here is an example summarized code of what I'm trying to do:

**main_file.py**

```
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, Update, KeyboardButton, Bot, InputMediaPhoto
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, ConversationHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, CallbackContext
import surveys  # this file contains each survey as a function with its own ConversationHandler

token = ''

MENU, USER, CHAT_ID, USER_ID, FINISHED = map(chr, range(1,6))

END = ConversationHandler.END


def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    """Initialize the bot"""

    context.user_data[CHAT_ID] = update.message.chat_id
    text = 'Select an option:'
    reply_keyboard = [
        ['Complete Survey'],
        ['EXIT'],
    ]

    context.bot.send_message(
        context.user_data[CHAT_ID],
        text=text,
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(reply_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True)
    )

    return MENU


def exit(update:Update, context:CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Exit from the main menu"""
    context.bot.send_message(
        context.user_data[CHAT_ID],
        text='OK bye!',
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )
    return END


def abrupt_exit(update:Update, context:CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Exit the main conversation to enter the survey conversation"""

    return END


def survey_start(update:Update, context:CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Asks for the user_id in order to determine which survey to offer"""
    text = 'Please type in your company ID'
    context.bot.send_message(
        context.user_data[CHAT_ID],
        text=text,
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )
    return USER


def survey_select(update:Update, context:CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Search database to find next survey to complete"""
    user = str(update.message.text)
    chat_id = context.user_data[CHAT_ID]
    context.user_data[USER_ID] = user

    """Search database with user_id and return survey to complete"""
    survey = 'survey_a'     # this value is obtained from the database

    runSurvey = getattr(surveys, survey)   # I used getattr to load functions in a different module
    runSurvey(Update, CallbackContext, user, chat_id, token)

    return FINISHED


def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Survey conversation
    survey_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[
            MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^Complete Survey$'), survey_start),
        ],

        states={
            USER: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.text, survey_select),
            ],
            FINISHED: [
                # I'm guessing here I should add something to exit the survey ConversationHandler
            ],
        },
        fallbacks=[
            CommandHandler('stop', exit),
        ],
    )


        # Initial conversation
    conv_handler=ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[
            CommandHandler('start', start),
        ],
        states={
            MENU: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^Complete Survey$'), abrupt_exit),
                MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^EXIT$'), exit),
            ],
        },
        allow_reentry=True,
        fallbacks=[
            CommandHandler('stop', exit),
        ],
    )

    dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler, group=0)  # I used separate groups because I tried ending
    dispatcher.add_handler(survey_handler, group=1)  # the initial conversation and starting the other

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**surveys.py** This is where each survey is with its own conversation and functions to call. Basically I enter survey_A (previously selected) and am trying to use it as the main()

```
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, Update, \
    KeyboardButton, Bot, InputMediaPhoto
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, ConversationHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, \
    CallbackContext

NEXT_QUESTION, LAST_QUESTION, CHAT_ID = map(chr, range(1,4))

END = ConversationHandler.END

def exit(update:Update, context:CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Exit from the main menu"""
    context.bot.send_message(
        context.user_data[CHAT_ID],
        text='OK bye!',
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )
    return END


def first_q(update:Update, context:CallbackContext, chat_id:str) -> None:
    """First survey_A question"""

    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id,
        text='What is your name?',
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )
    return NEXT_QUESTION


def last_q(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Last survey_A question"""

    update.message.reply_text(
        'How old are you?', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )
    return LAST_QUESTION

def survey_a(update:Update, context:CallbackContext, user:str, chat_id: str, token:str) -> None:
    """This function acts like the main() for the survey A conversation"""
    print(f'{user} will now respond survey_a')
    CHAT_ID = chat_id   # identify the chat_id to use
    updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)   # here I thought of calling the Updater once more

    survey_a_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[
            MessageHandler(Filters.text, first_q),
        ],
        states={
            NEXT_QUESTION: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.text, last_q),
            ],
            LAST_QUESTION: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.text, exit),
            ],

        },
        allow_reentry=True,
        fallbacks=[
            CommandHandler('stop', exit),
        ],
    )

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(survey_a_handler, group=0)  # I only want to add the corresponding
                                                               # survey conversation handler

    first_q(Update, CallbackContext, CHAT_ID)
```

I run the code and it breaks at surveys.py line 23, in first_q:
**context.bot.send_message(**
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'send_message'

I assume my logic with the conversation handler is way off.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been developing telegram bots for about a year now, and I hope the best approach is to structure your project first. Let me explain that all in detail.

### "Foldering"

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0JAe.png)

Basically, all the code is in the `src` folder of the project. Inside the `src` folder there is another sub-folder called `components` which includes all the different sections of your bot you want to work on (i.e your quiz_1, quiz_2, ...) and `main.py` file which includes the 'core' of the bot. However in the root directory of the project (which is just your project folder) you can see `bot.py` file which serves just as a runner file. So nothing more in there except just:

```
import src.main from main

if '__name__' == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Tips

So regarding your questionnaire:

- I would recommend using just strings as keys for the states instead of mapping them to random values. Basically you can do just like **`"MAIN_MENU"`**, **`"STATE_ONE"`** , **`"STATE_TWO"`** and so on, but be sure to return the same string in the callback function!
- The overall logic of the PTB library is like:
  Telegram API server -> PTB `Updater()` class -> `Dispatcher()` (which is `updater.dispatcher` in your code) -> Handlers -> callback function -> <- *user*.
  The reason arrows point to user and back to callback function is because there is an interaction of your bot's logic and user, so that user's response goes back to your callback function code.
- I recommend not choosing callback function names as like 'first_question' or 'second_question'. Instead name it like `get_question()` use that function to retrieve question data from other source so that it can be dynamic. So for example, you will have a dictionary of different questions with keys of question number - simple, right? And then you will write a function that will send user a question according to its state and picking the right question with the right key from the dictionary. By this you can add more questions to your dictionary and no need to change the code in the function because it will be dynamic (as long as you write the correct function that will work).
- In your `main.py` file have only one `main()` function which will hold the `Updater()` with the given token, because you **cannot** have more than one Updater() with the **same token**. It's like one bot can be accessed by only and only one app that is polling at a time. Polling - [visit here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling).

### Great news!

To support your bot development and follow the structured project creation, I have created a [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/nuriddinislamov/telegram-bot-template) that holds almost the same project structure as I tried to explain to you today. Feel free to check it out, clone it and play around. Just add your token to `.env` file and run the bot.

### More resources

Check out these projects as well:

- https://github.com/ez-developers/traderbot/tree/master/bot
- https://github.com/ez-developers/equip.uz/tree/main/bot

As you will see in there `main.py` contains all the handlers and `src` folder contains all the different 'components' which are more of a like different parts of the bot.

If you need any help, I am here and more than happy to answer any of your questions.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough response... I'll check it out tomorrow!

Comment: I went through your traderbot code and it is very well structured. I will restructure my bot using this logic. Thanks again

Comment: No worries at all. I am happy to help) And just as a little support, could you vote up the answer? (I'm still a bit newbie here, so some points would help me out somehow) cheers :)

Comment: Im also a newbie and can't upvote yet but your response is the logic I was looking for. I will upvote when I can

Comment: Oh, sure thing. No worries at all then!